# How can I batch checkAndDelete in BigTable using HBase API?

Tags: google-cloud-bigtable

I understand that we can do [checkAndDelete](https://hbase.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/hadoop/hbase/client/Table.html#checkAndDelete-byte:A-byte:A-byte:A-org.apache.hadoop.hbase.filter.CompareFilter.CompareOp-byte:A-org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.Delete-) on BigTable using the HBase API. I wonder if there is a way for me to submit a list of checkAndDelete so that I don't need to do them one by one? I mostly worry about the performance about non-batching processing...

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The HBase API doesn't offer a bulk option for `checkAnd*` methods.  The HBase API is backed by a gRPC protobuf API, which is natively asynchronous. You can use the underlying API to construct a high throughput application.

A WORD OF WARNING: this is mostly undocumented in our public facing documentation, but the source code should provide enough instruction on how to construct your application.  There are active users of this API, including Apache Beam's [`BigtableIO`](https://github.com/apache/beam/blob/master/sdks/java/io/google-cloud-platform/src/main/java/org/apache/beam/sdk/io/gcp/bigtable/BigtableIO.java). TODO: [document this feature](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/cloud-bigtable-client/issues/1233), feel free to comment or vote on the feature.

At a high level, here's what you'd have to do:

```
  AbstractBigtableConnection btConn = (AbstractBigtableConnection) connection;

  // BigtableSession can also be constructed by passing in a BigtableOptions.
  BigtableSession session = btConn.getSession();

  // AsyncExecutor encapsulates the notion of a "batch" of RPCs
  // that need to be completed as a unit.
  AsyncExecutor executor = session.createAsyncExecutor();

  // This listenable future will inform you when the request is done,
  // and if there were any exceptions.  
  // You can attach a FutureCallback
  ListenableFuture<CheckAndMutateRowResponse> response = 
      executor.checkAndMutateRowAsync(checkAndMutateRowRequest);

  // do more async work

  // Make sure all of the RPCs are complete.
  asyncExecutor.flush();
```

For reference, here's more information about [`ListenableFuture` and `FutureCallback`](https://github.com/google/guava/wiki/ListenableFutureExplained).  You can also dig into [`BigtableBufferedMutator`](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/cloud-bigtable-client/blob/cbigtable-client-0.9.5.1/bigtable-hbase-parent/bigtable-hbase/src/main/java/com/google/cloud/bigtable/hbase/BigtableBufferedMutator.java) for some suggestions on how to handle exceptions.

You can create a `CheckAndMutateRowRequest` by following the implementation of [`BigtableTable.checkAndDelete`](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/cloud-bigtable-client/blob/cbigtable-client-0.9.5.1/bigtable-hbase-parent/bigtable-hbase/src/main/java/com/google/cloud/bigtable/hbase/BigtableTable.java#L380).

Comment: Thanks so much! make sense to me

Comment: Hi, also I tried to create a `CheckAndMutateRowRequest` as in `BigtableTable.checkAndDelete(..)`. but I haven't been able to figure out how to get a `HBaseRequestAdapter`. May I know what's the easiest way to get it? I have a `AbstractBigtableConnection` and a `BigtableTable`. Thanks!